# Characterization of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space for which there exists a constant $\beta<\infty$ such that for every finite-dimensional subspace $B$ of $X$ , $d(B,\ell_2^n)\le\beta$ (where $\dim B=n$). Then $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space.

$d(B,\ell_2^n):$ Banach-Mazur distance

$\ell_2^n=(\mathbb{R}^n,||\cdot||_2)$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that it's enough to show $X$ is isomorphic to a space where the parallelogram law holds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-known theorem; implicit in Grothendieck's *Résumé*; clean proof [published by Joichi in 1966](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-02/S0002-9939-1966-0198187-1/).  Since the paper is in free access, I only describe the idea loosely.

Let $S$ be the lattice of finite-dimensional subspaces of $X$. For each $B\in S$, let $T_B$ be an isomorphism of $B$ onto a Euclidean space with indicated distortion bound. For each fixed $x\in X$, define a function $F_x:S\to [0,\infty)$ by $F_x(B)=0$ if $x\in B$, and by $F_x(B)=|T_Bx|^2$ otherwise. Then **average** $F_x$ over all $B$, and declare the result to be $\|x\|^2$. Finally, check that $\|\cdot\|^2$ satisfies the parallelogram law (which it does, being  the average of functions that do).

The averaging process amounts to constructing an invariant mean on $S$. Some functions $F:S\to\mathbb R$   have the limit $\lim_S F (B)$ (limit makes sense since $S$ is directed by inclusion). A form of Hahn-Banach theorem extends this limit to an appropriately controlled linear functional on all bounded functions $S\to \mathbb R$.

The comparability of $\|\cdot\|$ to the original norm follows from the fact that  the Hahn-Banach extension of $\lim_S F$ is pinched between $\liminf_S F$ and $\limsup_S  F$.

Comment: Last time I had checked (3 years ago), it was impossible to find a copy of the Résumé. Today I check again: someone (thank you!) TeXed it and made it [available online](http://www.ime.usp.br/acervovirtual/textos/estrangeiros/grothendieck/produits_tensoriels_topologiques/files/produits_tensoriels_topologiques.pdf) (see in particular the legendary tableau p.30). Now it only remains to translate it English...But there is [this book](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=MBK-52).

Comment: @julien Nice. No need to translate it into English, everyone should learn French. Of course.